# How can I change qualities (text, fill, etc.) of a grouped object?

Tags: vba, powerpoint, group

My question is generic because I've run into this multiple times for other aspects of an object.

I have a group of blocks that each contain a date (think of a calendar). I am using macros to revise the date based on the current date. However I need to have those blocks grouped so I can animate the collection together.

I believe I have a long workaround, but it involves code to ungroup, make the change, regroup, reconfigure animation, reassign the trigger, etc.

It seems the simple solution would be to directly modify the text of the grouped object if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grouped shapes can be accessed via the parent shape's `GroupItems` property.

Eg for a slide containing a single group consisting of several rectangles:

```vb
Sub Tester()
    Dim s As Shape, e As Shape
    
    With ActivePresentation.Slides(1)
        For Each s In .Shapes
            Debug.Print "--- " & s.Name & " ---"
            
            'loop group items...
            For Each e In s.GroupItems
                Debug.Print e.Name
                e.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "OK"
            Next e
            
            'address a specific sub-shape
            With s.GroupItems("Rectangle 4").TextFrame.TextRange
                .Text = "Hi"
            End With
            
        Next s
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: [In my best Doc Emmett Brown impersonation:] It works! 
Thank you so much! Have you been told today that you are a Rockstar?

Comment: Glad that was useful